# CKEditor - For each attribute with class name do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jwplayer

I'm trying to get the value of an attribute for each element with a  class name.

Here is my code:

```
var textareaId;

$(document).ready(function () {
    textareaId = $('#tiny_mce_block').find('textarea').attr('id'); // 
    ckeditor_init();
});

function ckeditor_init() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(textareaId, {
        allowedContent: true,
          on: {
            instanceReady: function (evt) {
                var editor = this;
                var data = editor.getData();
                var body = $(editor.document.getBody());

                jwplayer("video_block_sous_titres").onTime(function (event) {
                    $.each(**SELECT CLASS .ST**, function () { // HOW SELECT ELEMENTS WHERE THE CLASS IS 'st'
                        var d = SELECT DATA-TIME-START ; // HOW GET CONTENT OF ATTRIBUTE NAMED 'data-time-start'
                        var f = SELECT DATA-TIME-END; // HOW GET CONTENT OF ATTRIBUTE NAMED 'data-time-end'
                        if (d <= event.position && event.position <= f) {
                            if ($(this).attr("class") !== "active") {
                                $(".st").removeClass("active"); // HOW REMOVE THE CLASS 'active'
                                $(this).addClass("active"); // HOW ADD THE CLASS 'active'
                            }
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass("active"); // HOW REMOVE THE CLASS 'active'
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In my textarea I have this:

```
<span class="st" id="1" data-time-start="0.29" data-time-end="1.259" data-time-moy="0.1938">mardi </span>
<span class="st" id="2" data-time-start="2.048" data-time-end="5.406" data-time-moy="0.10832258064516">qualité sécurité efficacité </span>
```

**First question :**
In my loop  where JWPlayer is called, How can I select for each element which have Class `.st`, the value of attribute named `data-time-start`  and `data-time-end` ?

**Second question:**
After that, How to add or remove class `active` to this `.st` (with which method ?) ?

I tried to get the content of attribute like that but no way:

```
var st = el.find('#20');
console.log(st.getAttribute('data-time-start'));
```

MY FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/415/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't see the JW Player in this fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with this :

```
function jwplayer_underligne_st() {
        jwplayer("video_block_sous_titres").onTime(function (evt) {
            //var st = $(CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].window.getFrame().$).contents().find('.word');
            var st = $(CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].window.getFrame().$).contents().find('.st');
            $.each(st, function () {
                $this = $(this);
                var d = $this.attr("data-time-start");
                var f = $this.attr("data-time-end");
                if (d <= evt.position && evt.position <= f) {
                    if ($this.attr("class") !== "active") {
                        $this.addClass("active");
                    }
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```